# Why it is not printing the age entered by the user?

Tags: c

where is the error?, It should print out the age entered by the user to the student 0 of struct

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Students
{
    int age;
    int id;
    char name[30];
    int grade;
};

void main(void)
{
    struct Students *student[10]; // Array of Pointers to Structs.
    // Containing (10) Pointers (student) to Structs. To save memory unlike the normal array
    printf("Enter your Age: ");
    scanf("%d", &student[0]->age);
    printf("Age equals: %d", student[0]->age);
}
```

Comment: Hint: `struct X* y[n]` does *not* allocate any memory. These are pointers to *nothing* and your comment should read "Array of pointers to structs (unallocated)". They **must** be allocated. Use `calloc()` if you want dynamic allocation.

Comment: Note: Pointers do not "save memory". In fact, using a pointer uses (incrementally) more memory since not only do you have the struct, and the associated memory allocation tracking jazz in the background, but the pointer itself. Using a regular array is always going to be more memory efficient, but it limits what you can do with the array, as it's bound to the scope of that function call.

Comment: You either need to fill in your array of _pointers_ [in a loop]. Or, the TL;DR is change to `struct Students student[10];` and change [all] `student[0]->age` into `student[0].age`

Answer (score 3):

You have an array of ten *pointers* to `Students` structs, but each of those pointers has not been initialized.

As a result, undefined behavior is invoked when you dereference any of those pointers.

You should either dynamically allocate memory for each pointer to point to, or change your array to:

```
struct Students student[10];
```

This automatically allocates space on the stack for ten `Students` structs. At that point you can read an age with:

```
scanf("%d", &student[i].age);
```

As a sidenote, I think your pluralization is backwards. If your struct `Students` only hold info on a single student, then `Student` would be a better name, and `students` would be an apt name for an array of those structs.

You should also check the return value of `scanf`. If a single integer has been successfully read, `scanf` will return `1`. Do not assume your user will enter valid information. Checking the return value of `scanf` gives you the option of handling that scenario before it can create further runtime bugs.